# knockout.js and observable not updating, even with breakpoint step through

Tags: knockout.js

I have an issue where an observable is not updating, even when I step through and even when I try to manually update it, it still retains the same older value.  Below if `self.divisionId` changes, the computed observable `self.divisionBrackets` runs.  The `self.divisionBracketId(divisionBrackets[0].Id)` runs and has a different value then the previous, but when I step out of it, the `self.divisionBracketId` still has same value?  The before and after logging show the same value even though it was updated with a different.

You can view the link [here](https://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/widgets/brackets?version=1&eventid=30&slug=event).

```
 function Brackets() {

        var self = this;

        self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
        self.divisionId = ko.observable();
        self.divisionBracketId = ko.observable();
        self.divisions = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.brackets = [];

        self.divisionBrackets = ko.computed(function () {
            var divisionId = self.divisionId();
        self.divisionBracketId(null);

        var divisionBrackets = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.brackets, function(bracket) {
            return bracket.DivisionId == divisionId;
        });

        console.log("Division Brackets Count: " + divisionBrackets.length);

        if (divisionBrackets.length > 0) {
            console.log("Selected Division Bracket ID: " + divisionBrackets[0].Id);
            console.log("Before Update: " + self.divisionBracketId());
            self.divisionBracketId(divisionBrackets[0].Id);
            console.log("After Update: " + self.divisionBracketId());
        }

        return divisionBrackets;
        });

        self.search = function() {
            self.loaded(true);
            resize();
        };

        self.divisionBracketId.subscribe(function(_) {
            app.showProgress();
        });

        self.init = function (options) {

            self.divisions(options.divisions);
            self.brackets = options.brackets;

            app.applyBindings();
        };

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing a subscribe like Jeff said.

```
self.divisionBrackets = ko.computed(function () {
            var divisionId = self.divisionId();

            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.brackets, function(bracket) {
                return bracket.DivisionId == divisionId;
            });
        });

        self.divisionBrackets.subscribe(function (divisionBrackets) {
            if (divisionBrackets.length > 0) {
                self.divisionBracketId(divisionBrackets[0].Id);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for a computed observable to update, there must be a read of another observable somewhere within the function.  If it does, the computed observable will have a dependency on that observable.

Although you read the `divisionId` within the filter function, there is no guarantee that the function is ever called.  And upon initialization, it never is because `self.brackets` is initially an empty array.

To fix this, just read the id outside of the filter function.  The computed will then update anytime the `divisionId` changes.  Also, consider making `brackets` observable too, that way if that array changes, it will still update.

```
self.divisionBrackets = ko.computed(function () {
    self.divisionBracketId(null);
    var divisionId = self.divisionId(); 
    var divisionBrackets = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.brackets, function(bracket) {
        return bracket.DivisionId == divisionId;
    });

    if(divisionBrackets.length > 0)
        self.divisionBracketId(divisionBrackets[0].Id);

    return divisionBrackets;
});
```

Comment: This still does the same thing.  brackets was an observable, I just removed it.  Like I said I put a breakpoint in this and it gets hit.

Comment: Should that be `divisionBrackets[0].Id` or `divisionBrackets[0].DivisionId`?

Comment: "Id", since that is binding to the second dropdown list. I added console logging to show what is being updated.

Comment: One thing to note here is that since you're setting the value of the `divisionBracketId` twice, that may cause issues with the rendering. In fact, now that I think about it, I don't think you should be setting values within your computed observable in the first place. If you intend to set values in response to a change, you should either make those values computed or subscribe to those changes to perform the updates.

Comment: I fixed it by removing it from the computed, and adding a `subscribe` to the `divisionBrackets` and updated it through there.  I could of worn Ive done this before.